# Not all code paths return a value PigLatin

Tags: c#, methods

I know there's tons of these questions, and I've tried every single one. Why is this outputting the error: `not all code paths return a value`?

```
using System;

namespace PigLatin
{
    public class Translate
    {
        public static string Transfer(string input)
        {

            string firstChar = "";
            string lastChars = "";
            int x;
            string vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";

            string[] pieces = input.Split(null);

            try
            {
                foreach (string piece in pieces)
                {
                    lastChars = piece.Substring(1);
                    firstChar = piece.Substring(0, 1);

                    x = vowel.IndexOf(firstChar);

                    if (x == -1)
                    {
                        var pigLatin = lastChars + firstChar + "ay";
                        return pigLatin;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var pigLatin = firstChar + lastChars + "way";
                        return pigLatin;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter word to translate: ");
            var toTranslate = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(Transfer(toTranslate));
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

- Changing the variables in `Transfer` to `const`:

  ```
      const string firstChar = "";
      const string lastChars = "";
      int x;
      const string vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";
  ```
- Getting rid of the if statement and using an operator

  ```
  var pigLatin = ""; 
  x == -1 ? pigLatin = lastChars + firstChar + "ay" : pigLatin = firstChar + lastChars + "way"
  return pigLatin;
  ```

What is causing the error?

Comment: What happens if there is an exception? You write the error to the console, and then.. continue without returning a value. Also, if there is nothing in `pieces`, the for loop won't execute, and.. you don't execute a `return` statement.

Comment: you are missing a return statement!

Comment: Also, why would "not all code paths return a value" indicate to you that making variables constant would help?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I read it on some `SO` question.

Comment: For a function that returns a value (not `void`), it must be impossible for execution to exit the function by any means except for returning a value (or an uncaught exception). That is what "not all code paths return a value" means. Look at your code for the method, trace through the possible ways it could execute, and make sure all of them end in "return (something)".

Comment: @Blorgbeard That makes a lot of sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement after your try and catch block

```
using System;

namespace PigLatin
{
  public class Translate
  {
    public static string Transfer(string input)
    {

        string firstChar = "";
        string lastChars = "";
        int x;
        string vowel = "AEIOUaeiou";

        string[] pieces = input.Split(null);

        try
        {
            foreach (string piece in pieces)
            {
                lastChars = piece.Substring(1);
                firstChar = piece.Substring(0, 1);

                x = vowel.IndexOf(firstChar);

                if (x == -1)
                {
                    var pigLatin = lastChars + firstChar + "ay";
                    return pigLatin;
                }
                else
                {
                    var pigLatin = firstChar + lastChars + "way";
                    return pigLatin;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return 1; //or add any valid return value. This is your missing statement
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter word to translate: ");
        var toTranslate = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Transfer(toTranslate));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. `1` has type `int` and cannot be returned in a method declared as returning `string`. It would not have been enough to make the code do the right thing anyway.

Comment: @hvd The OP asked what is missing, I have added in the comments that you can return any value, not just `1`. It is up to the OP to fix it with an appropriate return value. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's why: If an exception happens and the catch triggers, you don't return a value.

```
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        return ""; // this should fix the error message.
    }
```

Comment: This may be enough to get the compiler to stop issuing an error message, but it's not enough to make the code do the right thing.

Comment: @hvd The op specifically asked "What is causing the error?" and I answered that.  He didn't ask us to fix his code to properly render pig latin. You owe me an "up vote". :P

Comment: That would have been fair enough if `return "";` had been the right thing to do after getting an exception, there would've been some sense in ignoring the rest of the OP's code, but it almost certainly isn't.

Comment: Haha! I see the OP selected someone else's answer that came later and won't even compile.  Sometimes this site just makes me shake my head.